# Entity Framework Inheritance and Relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I'm trying to implement TPH inheritance with Entity Framework 6 Code First and am having problems with a relationship from my inherited types.

My code is

```
public abstract class Base...

public class Inherited1 : Base
{
public virtual Type1 Rel { get; set; }
...

public class Inherited2 : Base
{
public virtual Type1 Rel {get;set;}
...
```

So the inherited types have the "same" relationship. The inheritance itself works fine, but the problem I'm having is that the relationship to the table Type1 will be added twice (logical...) and the other relationship is from Inherited2.Id to Type1.Id instead of Inherited2.Type1Id to Type1.Id that the first relationship is (correctly).

I'm not sure if I made any sense explaining this and with the partial code sample with changed type names, but I hope you got the point. Ask for more details if you need any.

I probably could implement this correctly with

**UPDATE**
I've created a sample Github repo to demonstrate the issue. Feel free to tell me what I'm doing wrong. https://github.com/antsim/EntityFrameworkTester

Comment: what you are using? Fluent API or Annotations ? in both cases, show some code of what you are using

Comment: The only fluent API related to these relationships is this
    modelBuilder.Entity<Type1>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Inherited1)
                .WithRequired(x => x.Type1)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete();

Comment: I added in my answer below the both cases TPT and TPH for your reference

Comment: It seems I got the relations corrected. I was accidently missing the other end definition for Inherited2.Type1 relation. So Type1 didn't have anything related to Inherited2. I added it there and EF generated the relations correctly. Downside with this kind of setup is that I cannot have Delete on cascade on both relations for obvious reasons, but at least it's working. I'll test it a bit more and confirm that it's actually working.

Comment: Actually the relation works if I have ICollection<Inherited2> in my Type1 class, but if I just have public Inherited2 PropertyName {get;set;}, it doesn't work. Go figure... And I'm trying to use fluent api with .Entity<Type1>().HasOptional(x => x.Inherited2Property).WithRequired(x => x.Rel);

Comment: i am sorry I do not have an answer, but would you mind to tell me how did you solve the problem here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194151/xmlserializer-stopped-working-after-updates  

(I couldn't find a way to ask a direct question)

Comment: Sorry @elty123 , I can't remember anymore. Have you tried the marked answer if it solves your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following

1- if you want TPT

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Inherited1>()
            .ToTable("Inherited1s")
            .HasKey(x => x.YourKey)
            .HasRequired(x=>Type1)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x=>Type1Id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Inherited2>()
            .ToTable("Inherited2s")
            .HasKey(x => x.YourKey)
            .HasRequired(x=>Type1)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x=>Type1Id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

2 - if you want TPH

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Base>()
            .ToTable("YourTableName")
            .HasRequired(m=>m.Type1)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(m=>m.Type1Id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(); // true or false as you want
```

for more details you might check this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)

based on the sample you provided

- `Attachment` and `Document` are inherited from File and you are using `TPH` which means One table will be created with a `Discriminator` field.
- `Document` and `FileContainer` has a relation of type 0..1 which means a Foreign Key `FileContainerId` should be created in the `Document` hence in the `File` table
- `FileContainer` and `Attachment` has a relation of type 0..n, then another nullable foreign key will be created in the table File

in the example you provided, I made the following changes

1. Add FileContainerId to the table Document
2. Add FileContainerAttachmentId to the table Attachment
3. The changes made on the TestContext was

   ```
           modelBuilder.Entity<FileContainer>()
               .HasOptional(x => x.Document)
               .WithMany()
               .HasForeignKey(t => t.DocumentId)
               .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

           modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
               .HasRequired(t => t.FileContainer)
               .WithMany()
               .HasForeignKey(t => t.FileContainerId)
               .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

           modelBuilder.Entity<Attachment>()
               .HasRequired(t => t.FileContainer)
               .WithMany()
               .HasForeignKey(t => t.FileContainerAttachmentId)
               .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
   ```

the output was correct ( File table contains discriminator field in addition to two relations one for the document with the container and the other for the attachment with the container).

A better solution in my opinion is:

1. To add a class `FileType ( Id, Name)` with values `Attachment`, `Document`, and add it as a foreign key in `File`
2. To add only one relation 0..n between the `FileContainer` and `File`
3. To validate that only one record in the File of type document to same container

Hope this will help you

Comment: You have .WithMany in the TPH example. I got it working like that, but what if I have 0..1 in the Type1?

Comment: 0..1 is a special case of 0..n where n=1, so the same logic can be applied but instead of HasRequired, you should use HasOptional

Comment: I've made a github repo to reproduce and test these issues. If someone has time, they could help there. I've tried to describe the wanted result and current issues in readme.md. https://github.com/antsim/EntityFrameworkTester

Comment: @AnttiSimonen I reviewed the sample and explained what happened in your model , and also I proposed another solution

Comment: A huge thank you for your answer. That basically solves the problem. It seems I was missing the foreignkey fields and I'm still having a hard time to understand why .WithMany is needed for example for the FileContainer -Document relation which is not 0 to many? I'm still having some issues when saving the data as EF complains it cannot resolve a correct order of inserts. I already had to put some relationships optional and I'm still fighting with the rest of the issues.

Comment: kindly mark my post and answer and vote it up if it helped you, and regarding the other issues, make a new question for that